# Trait 'Laravelista\Comments\Comments\Traits\Comments' not found

Tags: php, class, laravel-5, traits

I just downloaded a search class for laravel called [laravelista/comments](https://github.com/laravelista/comments)

The documentation is pretty scanty  so I do not really understand everything.

Basically,when I try to after typing in my details in and pressing `submit` in'localhost:8000/login' it directs me to laravel PrettyPageHandler and shows me this error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Trait 'Laravelista\Comments\Comments\Traits\Comments' not found
```

I have already downloaded laravelista/comments and run all the commands like:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravelista\Comments\Providers\CommentsServiceProvider" --tag=migrations

php artisan migrate


php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravelista\Comments\Providers\CommentsServiceProvider" --tag=config

php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravelista\Comments\Providers\CommentsServiceProvider" --tag=public --force
```

but I still get that error

In my User.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Laravelista\Comments\Comments\Traits\Comments;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use Comments;


    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Have a look in your vendor file, can you find the specified Trait? The folder path will follow the namespace you mentioned. (Laravelista / comments / ...)

Comment: Yeah I found the trait at:`C:\xampp2\htdocs\site\vendor\laravelista\comments\src\Commentable.php`

Comment: Where did you get `use Laravelista\Comments\Comments\Traits\Comments;` from? There's documentation that tells you how to install stuff: https://github.com/laravelista/comments#add-commenter-trait-to-your-user-model and https://github.com/laravelista/comments#add-commentable-trait-to-models

Comment: I got the documentation from https://devhub.io/repos/laravelista-comments

Answer (score 0):

I just had to change User.php to

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;


use Laravelista\Comments\Commenter;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable,Commenter;



    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

I used the wrong `use`